# How to select app-execution reparse points in QFileDialog

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside6, qfiledialog

When I select a reparse point from **%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps** (e.g. julia.exe) using a QFileDialog and click the `Open` button an error dialog pops up

[image: Error dialog]

Clicking `Ok` just closes the error dialog but doesn't close the file browser window.

Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. Click the Browse button and select any .exe file from **%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps** and the error dialog pops up.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout

class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("Browse")
        self.le = QLineEdit()
        self.lo = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lo.addWidget(self.button)
        self.lo.addWidget(self.le)
        self.setLayout(self.lo)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.open_browser)

    def open_browser(self):
        self.le.clear()
        answer = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open")
        if answer[0] != "":
            self.le.setText(answer[0])
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

I'm aware that **%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps** is in PATH and I do not actually need to select the reparse point file anyway but this is an error dialog that some users of my app may encounter and I'd like to deal with it somehow.

The question is, how can I select the reparse point file and then return it from the QFileDialog? Is there a way to catch the error that causes the error dialog to pop up and then simply return the full path as the `answer` in the above code snippet?

Win: 10
Python: 3.10.8
PySide6: 6.5.2

Things tried & considered:

- Tried using the QFileDialog constructor directly and calling open() to show the dialog but the result is the same.
- Tried catching the error in a Slot for the `QDialog.accepted` signal but this is triggered too late. The error dialog pops up before the Slot is processed.
- Using option (`QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks`) did not help. Same error dialog pops up.
- Considered using Qt's own file browser (`QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog`). I don't want to do this because the Windows users of my app are accustomed to their native file browser.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "select any .exe file from %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps"? Do you intend that the user should be able to *just type* `julia.exe` in the file name field, no matter the currently shown directory in the file dialog, and press Return/Ok to accept that input?

Comment: The dialog isn't showing an ***error***, it's showing a ***warning***. The message correctly states that a reparse point "*cannot be accessed by the system*", which is useful information for the user. There's really no good reason for you to try to handle this situation yourself. The user isn't seeing anything they wouldn't normally see when using a Windows file-dialog; in fact, they may well *expect* to see that warning, and be confused when they don't. You can't do anything useful with such files (other than show yet another warning), so it's best to just let the system block access to them.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the comment. By selecting any .exe I mean any **existing** .exe. Users must have installed Julia from the Microsoft Store beforehand. Maybe a better example would have been `wsl.exe` but the real use case is about selecting `julia.exe` so I went with that.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for commenting. The recommended way to run Julia on Windows is to use the Microsoft Store Julia. My app is sandboxing Julia so I'm running julia.exe in a child-process and using the %LocalAppData\Microsoft\WindowsApps\julia.exe works fine. All I want here is to get the full path to ..\WindowsApps\julia.exe returned from QFileDialog but clicking the Open button in the file-dialog *accesses* the file in some way and I don't want that. I just need the full path. Maybe the solution here is to edit the troubleshooting section of my app.

Comment: @ptsavol that's not what I asked. Please read again my question.

Comment: @musicamante The answer to your question is: no, that is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @ptsavol Ok, thank you. Please try to be understanding about my insistence: Qt is an extremely large toolkit, used on/with many different platforms/experience levels, so it's not always immediate to understand a request about an OS some of us may not be used to, especially if done by a new user we cannot possibly know anything about (AFAWK, you may be a pro just like as a newbie). No matter our experience, we may not know all aspects of each OS (for instance, I mostly use Linux), and in certain cases like yours it can be difficult to distinguish a legitimate request from an inexperienced one.